# How do I get element from within two iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to run code on a page but the element it is searching for is inside of an iframe inside of an iframe and I don't know how to get this to work without inspecting the element the second iframe is in. Below is the sample code:

```
var searchClass=document.getElementsByClassName("w3-bar w3-card-2 notranslate");
```

Easiest example of exactly what I'm talking about is if you go to this [example site](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_element_iframe) , there is the iframe "myFrame" inside of the iframe "iframeResult".

**My question is** using that example site as a reference, how would you search for a class inside of two different iframes (assuming they're from the same domain)?. I found the code below as an example but it would not open even the first one and I honestly don't know why:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeResult');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

[image: example of page I'm talking about]